# How to wait for popup window?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, puppeteer, chai

I trying to test my social media share buttons. I'm using puppeteer and chai to run the client-side tests. When the user clicks on the share button a pop-up window is opened for the relevant social media site. The window is triggered using the following code.

```
document.querySelector(".share .facebook").addEventListener("click", shareFacebook)

function shareFacebook(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    popupWindow(`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${window.location.href}&title=${"Test"}`, "test", window, 500, 220)
}

function popupWindow(url, title, win, w, h) {
    const y = win.top.outerHeight / 2 + win.top.screenY - ( h / 2);
    const x = win.top.outerWidth / 2 + win.top.screenX - ( w / 2);
    return win.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+y+', left='+x);
}
```

This all works fine, but I can't get my test to wait for the pop-up window. 
This is my test:

```
describe("share test", ()=>{

it.only("should open a facebook share window", async()=>{
        await page.evaluate(()=>{
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        })
        await page.waitForSelector("img.facebook", {visible:true})
/*      const nav = new Promise(res => browser.on('targetcreated', res)) */
        await page.click("img.facebook")
    /*  await nav */
        await page.waitFor(10000)

        pages = await browser.pages()
        for(let i=0; i< pages.length; i++){
            p = await pages[i].title();
            console.log(p)
        }

    })
})
```

The line `await page.waitFor(10000)` works and I get the Facebook title printed out but I don't want to use an unreliable wait time if possible. The line  `nav = new Promise(res => browser.on('targetcreated', res))` as recommended here [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50119325/in-puppeteer-how-to-wait-for-pop-up-page-to-finish-loading) doesn't work and I don't get the Facebook page printed out - though it is opening in the browser albeit after the test has run.

How can I get mocha to wait for the window to open before running the test?

Comment: Can you provide the code for `popupWindow` method?

Comment: Sorry overlooked that as it was in a different file. Added the function to the post now.

Answer (score 0):

Moving `const nav = new Promise(res => browser.on('targetcreated', res))` to after the initializing click event `await page.click("img.facebook")` seems to have done the trick. So the working code is now

```
it.only("should open a facebook share window", async()=>{
        await page.evaluate(()=>{
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        })
        await page.waitForSelector("img.facebook", {visible:true})
        await page.click("img.facebook")
        const nav = new Promise(res => browser.on('targetcreated', res))
        await nav
        pages = await browser.pages()
        for(let i=0; i< pages.length; i++){
            p = await pages[i].title();
            console.log(p)
        }

    })
```